# Django/Nginx Is there a way to get the original relative url of a browser request?

Tags: django, http, url, nginx, relative-path

If I have a django app running behind nginx, and the current address is

`http://www.foo.com/cat/dog/content.html`

with a web page that contains html like so,

`<img src="../../../../pic.png">`,

the browser will make a request to `http://www.foo.com/pic.png`, but is there any way to get the original relative url `../../../../pic.png`, or the number of `../`s server side, either in a django view or nginx?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The address is resolved in the browser, before the request is made.